# Get textBox cell value from datagrid winforms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]

I have button inside `DataGrid` (created by Edit Column), and `TextBox` same. I have created `CellClick` event on button. Now I want `TextBox` value which will be enter by user.

How can I get it?

I've tried

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        //Here i will get cell value which bind from database
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Now I want textBox value which will be enter by user" nothing is clear here. you want to show the selected cell value on somewhere or you want to insert to grid from textbox ? or insert data from grid txtbox?

Comment: Do you want the value of Grid view cell to the text box?
if (e.RowIndex>=0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                txtdeptid.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                txtdeptname.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            }

Comment: I have textBox inside datagrid which I added from EditColumn, I need that textBox value which be enter by user on CellClick event

Comment: if (e.RowIndex>=0)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
                txtdeptid.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                txtdeptname.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            }

Comment: Umair Rasheed, this line will give only cells value but not exact i want textBox values

Comment: Please check image link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

form load:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dataGridView1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;

        }
```

CellClick Event:

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
            row = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
            if (row.Cells[0].Value!=null && row.Cells[1].Value != null && row.Cells[2].Value != null) {
                textBox1.Text = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                textBox2.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                textBox3.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: My requirement is to get TextBox values which is reside in DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

I have used the CellContentClick and it works perfectly. I've also added a string variable that takes the value. This is my code:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        {
            string value = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(value);
        }
}
```

Comment: This will work only in case of dataBinding, but what about custom columns added? I need for custom column which contains TextBox

Comment: If you add some columns you have just to change the Cells index with the index of the column you want